# Array of object, how to make select options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a select where I select fields by name (`email`, `name`, `account`, etc), when I click on a field in an other select I have to show the database values for this field. I get then like this:
 `[{"name":"name1"},{"name":"name2"}]` or `[{"email":"email1"},{"email":"email2"}]` so I can't use a `value.name` or a `value.email` in `ngOptions` (but I have the name of the field in a scope var it helps)

I have tried with all options in `ngOptions` documentation for arrays and for object, one of the I retrieve the first element, other one a list of `[object Object]`.

I wan't to make a select where the value and the label are the same, like:

```
<option value="name1">name1</option>
<option value="name2">name2</option>
```

Comment: ` I can't use a value.name or a value.email in ngOptions` why?

Comment: Because the field selected is dynamic he gets name OR email OR ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
<select ng-model="selected"
      ng-options="name[utils.keys(name)[0]] for name in names">
</select>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ma2939ab/1/

Comment: That works, but if some one want to use it look in the jsFiddle where the utils.keys are defined ;)